# react-smooth-scrollbar programmatically change the scroll position?

Tags: smooth-scrolling

I'm using this scroll bar from idiotWu which works great so far:

https://github.com/idiotWu/react-smooth-scrollbar

What I need to do next is in my react project, I need to programatically change the scroll position.  In my project, when my fires `reactComponent.render()` again because of some things I'm doing, I need to scroll back to the top of the `<Scrollbar />`.   I don't see in the documentation any mention of how to do something like a `element.scrollTop()` or `<Scrollbar scrollPosition={0} />`.

I tried to manually set the transform translate3d of `<div class="scroll-content">`, but that didn't work because the scrollbar is saving it's scroll position value somewhere, and I don't know how to access it.

How do I reset the scroll to the beginning?  Alternatively, how do I state the scroll position?

---

**EDIT**
I also tried each of these but they all did not produce the results I wanted

```
export default class MyClass extends React.Component {
    render() {

        document.getElementById('panel').setPosition(0,0); // setPosition is not a defined method
        document.getElementById('panel').scrollTop=0; // had no effect

        scrollbar.setPosition(0,0); // scrollbar not defined
        scrollbar.scrollTop=0; //scrollbar not defined

        return (<Scrollbar id="panel">stuff</Scrollbar>);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `scrollbar.scrollTop = 0` or `scrollbar.setPosition(scrollbar.offset.x, 0)`.

Comment: Hi Dolphin, I edited my question to show that I tried your solutions, but they didn't produce the results.  See the edited part of my question for details.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!